# Why doesn't my text align to the centre?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, text-align

My Text doesn't align to the center where it should be, obviously you could add margin or padding or whatever you like but that doesn't solve the problem in the long run, especially if nobody knows what title will be in there.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/385zLos5/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="hover">
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <a>This is a long description, I don't know what to write here.</a>
            </div>
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445127040028-b1bdb9acd16e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=5f10c1c850239222d20e96ae1b8b5862">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
font-family: "Raleway", Century Gothic;
}

body {
margin: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

.hover {
width: 33.333333333333%;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

.hover > .description {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
}

.hover > img {
width: 105%;
filter: blur(5px);
transition: 0.3s ease;
margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px;
}

.hover:hover > img {
filter: blur(0px);
transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hover > .description > h3,
.hover > .description > h3:after {
position: absolute;
color: #fff;
z-index: 3;
transition: 0.3s ease;

}

.hover:hover > .description > h3 {
transition: 0.3s ease;

}

.hover > .description > a,
.hover > .description > a:after {
position: absolute;
color: #fff;
z-index: 3;
transition: 0.3s ease;

}

.hover:hover > .description > a {
transition: 0.3s ease;

}
```

Comment: Center horizontally, vertically, or both?

Comment: Sorry, mainly horizontally.

Comment: Probably cause of the `absolute positioning` or the `float`. Not sure; it's been a little while since I've messed with HTML/CSS.

Comment: The absolute positioning is required for the text to be on top of the img and the float is required for multiple `hover-class-divs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set `position: relative;` on parent and then `width: 100%` on `absolute` positioned child like this

```css
* {
    font-family: "Raleway", Century Gothic;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.hover {
    width: 33.333333333333%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.hover > .description {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    z-index: 5;
}

.hover > img {
    width: 105%;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px;
}

.hover:hover > img {
    filter: blur(0px);
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.hover:hover > .description > h3 {
    transition: 0.3s ease;  
}

.hover:hover > .description > a {
    transition: 0.3s ease;   
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="hover">
    <div class="description">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <a>This is a long description, I don't know what to write here.</a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300/000000/ffffff">
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make hover div relative position and description div absoute position inside it.

[jsfidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/7c05s4am/2/)

**CSS**

```
.hover {
    width: 33.333333333333%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution, with less headache, could be to just have the div have a background image

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif);
```

and then center the text in the div.

Comment: Then I would no longer be able to blur the background and un-blur on hover